# How do I best handle ajax requests that take a long time to complete?

Tags: php, ajax, node.js

Let me preface this question by saying I'm relatively new to architecting processor intensive web applications.  I've got a functional application built on a LAMP stack, and am now at the point in development where I have to implement for scale.

I've got a web server running PHP code that ssh's into a remote Windows machine to execute a batch process that can take about 15 to 45 seconds to complete depending on concurrency.  I'm using the SSH2 implementation provided by the [phpseclib pear library package](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net) to login to the remote machine to launch the batch file with [Sysinternals' PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553).  The PHP code looks something like this:

```
$remoteCommand = 'psexec -u username -p password -h cmd /C "C:\\automate_process.bat >> automate_process.log 2>>&1"';
$ssh_connection->exec($remoteCommand);
```

This essentially invokes automate_process.bat on the remote Windows machine from the web server hosting the php code.  However, the automate_process.bat file takes a while to execute and will sometimes cause the web server's PHP to timeout if there are concurrent users.  Increasing the max_execution_time value in php.ini doesn't solve the issue.

With PsExec, the `-d` switch will not wait for automate_process.bat to complete, and will allow the PHP script to continue without waiting.  So, problem solved on the max_execution_time front, but another issue arises:  notifying the end-user's browser that the automated_process is complete.  How can this be done in an effective manner?  What is seemingly needed is an architectural change in the application code.

At first I thought some kind of polling would do the trick--maybe long-polling?  I would just ping the remote windows Machine to see if the process was complete.  But everything I read says that long-polling is a severe burden on Apache which is what the remote Windows machine is running.  In addition, a good deal of writing on the web points to Node.js as a solution.  Is that really the solution to this type of problem?  Do I have to learn a new framework to make this operation robust as the application scales up?  I'm fine with that, but I want to know if I can mix-n-match PHP and Node.js.  If so, can anybody provide a simple example to get me started?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an AJAX request, one straightforward (but not necessarily ideal) option is to just omit the -d switch on PsExec so the script waits for it to complete, turn up the max_execution_time for that script in PHP, and increase the timeout on your AJAX call. That way the browser will just hold that connection open until it gets the output. Whether or not that is a good solution depends on a lot of factors.

If all of these AJAX requests are requesting the same data (or there are only a few distinct requests), and the data doesn't have to be up-to-the-second, you could create a cron job to periodically run that process on the server and store the output to a file (perhaps every 5 minutes), then your ajax call could just request that static file. If the information in the file is sensitive you'd need to add a layer of security, naturally.

Comment: The remote machine's automate_process.bat isn't dumping data to one static file.  It creates several files specific to the user logged in.  I don't think a cron is the answer.  I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "increase the timeout on your AJAX call" when what I really want is to minimize the amount of time it takes to get the data back.

Comment: What I meant about dumping to a file is that you could have a PHP file that periodically pings the remote machine as you showed above, then saves the data to a static file for later retrieval. But since most calls are distinct, that's not a good solution.

Comment: As for increasing the timeout on the ajax call, that would just prevent it from closing the connection and erroring out before the server sends back the data. It's basically the same as long-polling, but without interrupting the connection. It can be problematic with lots of concurrent connections, it depends upon your setup.

Answer (score 1):

If the processing time is what it is, I would setup the client to initiate the processing with the initial ajax request.  The server would start the process and reply 'processing'.  The cycle could be repeated with a 10 second delay between ajax requests from the client until the process is finished, you just have to track each client on the server...

Comment: But doesn't the multiple Ajax requests present a problem for apache?  Your solution sounds like polling, and my question is if a framework like Node.js or Websocket.IO or even Cometd makes sense to get updates from the remote machine doing the heavy processing.

Comment: My understanding of the problem with apache is that apache doesn't like open requests.  My proposed structure eliminates requests that stay open. Setting up a websocket as part of the initial request would be a great improvement on my proposed solution. Unless you know websockets are supported by all your clients, I would set it up as I initailly proposed because you will have to degrade non websocket clients to it anyway...

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think socket.io can handle non-websocket clients.  I decided to learn how to use socket.io in conjunction with node.js.